# How to debug "webpack.config.js" file?

Tags: webpack

I want to debug the "webpack.config.js" file, not the application using "devtool: 'source-map'". I want the webpack configuration file to be debugged. Is there any option?

Comment: Same as any other nodejs application. Or simply `console.log`.

Answer (score 34):

Simply run `webpack.js` in debug mode using nodejs. You can run the following on your terminal (assuming you are already in the directory with your node_modules present):

```
node --inspect node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --colors
```

I also found the VSCode debugger very intuitive for debugging when I was developing my own webpack loader. If you use VS Code you can have your `launch.json` have the following configuration:

```
{
        "type": "node", 
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Attach",
        "port": 5858
}
```

Then run the node-inspector with the following command:

```
node --inspect-brk=5858 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --colors
```

Finally, run the debug configuration by going to the debug tab, pick your configuration at the top, and then press the run configuration button.

Comment: Wonderful solution, it helped me to debug my Webpack.config file

Comment: You can point it to the webpack.config.js file, if that's needed:
`node --inspect-brk=9229 ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.js --colors`